# Is there a wiki system that can be easily "plugged-in" to an existing CakePHP application?

Tags: cakephp, module, wiki

I'm looking for a wiki system, that can easily be incorporated into an existing CakePHP application. I would have done it seperately from the CakePHP application, but the buyer requests that the user authorisation is done from the same tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while back unsuccessfully. Your question would indicate that nothing has changed.

I eventually went with a 3rd party standalone wiki.

I suggest that you choose a wiki with accessible php, create a loginWiki function in the UsersController and use it to inject the information into the hacked wiki login script. Thinking about it now, it shouldn't be too difficult.

You'll have to write a little php in the wiki to make it look at and save to the Cake users table.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a helper on any kind of source code example that might help...

Comment: Sorry, no, but from the cake side, you could probably call the wiki login from the cake auth login. If you can make the wiki live in app/vendors and it is written in php, there's no reason why you can't App::import it (unless there is a naming clash). If you have the enthusiasm, you could even make a component or plugin of it and post it in the bakery.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, if I do figure it out, I'll try to make a plugin that would handle this elegantly.